# How can I enable Hardmode?

Tags: terraria, terraria-mobile

What items do I need to make my world Hard Mode?

Comment: Please only use the [tag:ios] tag if it actually matters what version you are using, as this applies to all versions of Terraria the tag is unneeded.

Comment: @RonanForman Please roll back your edit; the mobile version has no hardmode thus the tag is important.

Comment: @Doorknob We are allowed to answer the question within the scope of all versions, as you have done. It's okay. It's better that way.

Comment: sorry i just never played pc version so i dont know whats only on pc and whats on console.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To enter hardmode, follow these steps:

1. Kill a [Voodoo Demon](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Voodoo_Demon) and take the [Guide Voodoo Doll](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide_Voodoo_Doll) it drops. Voodoo Demons spawn in [The Underworld](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Underworld).
2. Throw the doll into lava (in The Underworld).
3. Fight the [Wall of Flesh](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wall_of_Flesh) boss that you have just spawned.
4. Once you have killed the Wall of Flesh, you have just entered [Hardmode](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hardmode)!

On the mobile version of the game, you need to update your game to a minimum of 1.1.5822 on Android and 1.1.5536 on iOS to get the hardmode update. See Terraria wiki's [mobile version history](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mobile_Version_History) article for more information.

Hardmode content differs slightly between PC, [mobile](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mobile_version) and [console](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Console_version) version of the game. See their respective wiki articles for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Watch ImperfectLion's videos on YouTube, it shows you that he has Hardmode on iOS.but you have to download a bunch of files and watch tutorials thatbwill actually enable it onto your device.my opinion though is that you probably shouldnt try it because theres been some complaints about crashes and bosses and hardmode items not spawning.but i still recommend that you at least watch the tutorial that ImperfectLion suggests in the description of his Terraria videos. (I can't say which episode he mentions it, but I know that the title of the video was "Terraria-episode something-Demon Wings?").Other than that, yeah Hardmode is pretty much not available on iOS unless the creators make some sort of update or something...

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

First when you go into the Hellworld you need to find a voodoo demon. You will recognize it by the voodoo doll it carries while flying around. However, you could get unlucky and no demon will spawn. Anyway, after you kill it it will drop a voodoo doll of your guide. By this point in the game the guide is pretty much just an annoyance so the first thing you would do is probably drop it in lava, right? Well, if you do then the WoF will spawn, triggering Hardmode upon it's defeat. Hope that helped :D
It won't work on mobile btw