# Why can't I get a pwnhammer?

Tags: terraria-mobile

So.. I spent a good week and a half playing terraria on my android and met with some friends to join me. We finally managed to get to the Wall of Flesh, and me and my friends died quite a few times. Finally, I managed to defeat him by myself and was extrememly disappointed when I couldn't get the Pwnhammer. Did I do something wrong, or is this a bug of some sort?

Comment: The mobile version of terraria is lacking compared to the pc version. It may not even have the pwn hammer.

Comment: Well see I googled a lot of info about the ores and stuff I can get from using the pwnhammer and it all says that those ores are present in the mobile version so my suspicions are at its finest

Comment: what ores? (ive defeated the wall of flesh myself and not gotten the pwn hammer) furthermore hard mode does not excist in the mobile version, period. This is a fact. So if these 'ores' are hardmode 'ores' your sources are wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I enable Hardmode?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/135374/how-can-i-enable-hardmode)

Answer (score 3):

It is a feature that isn't really implemented yet. You can try the Pwnhammer by importing hacked worlds or hack your own world.

Answer (score 2):

Terraria for android devices does not include hardmode, which means beating the wall of flesh does not put you into it. It doesn't drop the pwnhammer either, but may drop other useful items.

Answer (score 1):

As of September 4 2014, the mobile version of Terraria on Google Play, iOS app store and Amazon app store have been updated to include most PC hardmode content such as the hardmode bosses, ores and armor. The minimum version required and release dates for each platform are

- iOS: **1.1.5536** released on Aug 27, 2014
- Amazon: **1.1.5822** released on Sep 1, 2014
- Google Play: **1.1.5822** released Sep 4, 2014

If you don't see hardmode content, you should check your game's version to see if it has been updated. See Terraria Wiki's [mobile version history](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mobile_Version_history) article for more information.