# How do I find Skeletron and where?

Tags: terraria

Where do I find Skeletron in Terraria? Is there any exact tools I should use?

Comment: Welcome to the site! In general we try to only ask one question per question. In addition, your second question [has already been asked and answered elsewhere](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/135374/how-can-i-enable-hardmode), so I've removed it.

Answer (score 4):

Skeletron is not "found" as such, but is rather summoned.

From the [wiki page](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Skeletron):

> Skeletron is summoned by speaking to the Old Man at the Dungeon's entrance, at night, who will die and spawn Skeletron when you select the “curse” option. If you speak to the Old Man during the day, he will ask you to return at night. You will only be able to summon Skeletron once per night, as the Old Man will not respawn until day.
>
> Skeletron can be summoned repeatedly this way until it is defeated. Once it is defeated, the Old Man will no longer appear. Skeletron can be re-summoned thereafter once the player acquires the Clothier Voodoo Doll. Equipping the Doll allows the player to kill the Clothier, which summons Skeletron. But this must be done at night.

The [Dungeon](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dungeon) is located near the far left or far right side of the map - its location will be randomly chosen when the world is created.

As to what you will want to defeat him, here are some options recommended by the [wiki strategy guide](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Skeletron_strategies):

- Ranged weapons

  - Minishark
  - Flamarang
  - Space Gun (perhaps with Meteor armour for mana-free usage)
  - Demon Bow (or Tendon Bow for Crimson worlds)
- Melee weapons

  - Fiery Greatsword
  - Flails (such as Ball O' Hurt or The Meatball)

Comment: Pro tip for finding the dungeon: if you pass the jungle biome, turn around and go back. If you pass the snow biome, you're going in the right direction.

Comment: @angussidney Wow really? That's handy to know. But how do you know that? Is it just by observation or is there some game mechanic to it?

Comment: I remember reading it somewhere, but I can't remember exactly where I found it. But all the worlds I have appear to follow this rule.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Terraria Wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Skeletron):

> ### Summoning
>
> Skeletron is summoned by speaking to the Old Man at the Dungeon's
>   entrance, at night, who will die and spawn Skeletron when you select
>   the “curse” option. If you speak to the Old Man during the day, he
>   will ask you to return at night. You will only be able to summon
>   Skeletron once per night, as the Old Man will not respawn until day.
>
> Skeletron can be summoned repeatedly this way until it is defeated.
>   Once it is defeated, the Old Man will no longer appear. Skeletron can
>   be re-summoned thereafter once the player acquires the Clothier Voodoo
>   Doll. Equipping the Doll allows the player to kill the Clothier, which
>   summons Skeletron. But this must be done at night.

Answer (score -2):

Skeletron is actually the old man at the dungeon and if you pick 'curse' it will do a summoning sequence where it looked like the old man was the cage and you helped him escaped.[image]